# Android button size changing

Tags: android

I have two buttons in my layout. They appear fine with padding around their sides. However, when I change the activity's `theme` to `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`

All of a sudden, the buttons become really small with no padding around them. Why is this happen? All it takes is for me to remove the theme attribute (remove NoTtitleBar) and that fixes them. What does that have to do with the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
```

instead. The one I was using before is for gingerbread and so it changes the default style of buttons, etc...